# What method gets called when you add two numbers in java?

Tags: java

What method gets called when you add two numbers in java? For example, in python when you do a + b, a.__ add __(b) gets called.

Comment: Time to look at the bytecode

Comment: There is no such thing in Java. Next step is bytecode

Comment: `iadd` is the bytecode command for int addition

Comment: Primitives don't use methods for basic arithmetic. You cannot override basic operators (like +, -, *, etc.).